# Question about computed equilibrium graph

Tags: equilibrium

[image]

When I was reading a paper about sulfuric acid decomposition,I couldn't understand this graph very well.[(link)](https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1021/ie990801e)

The caption says concentration but the vertical axis says mole(not mole/L or something related to concentration.)

And there's no mention on pressure. I think equilibrium is affected by the pressure.

Can someone explain this graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And there's no mention on pressure. I think equilibrium is affected by the pressure.

You have three reactions:

$\ce{H2SO4(l) <=> H2SO4(g)}\tag{1}$

$\ce{H2SO4(g) <=> H2O(g) + SO3(g)}\tag{2}$

$\ce{SO3(g) <=> SO2(g) + 1/2O2(g)}\tag{3}$

All of these are affected by pressure. From the context of the paper quoted by the OP, ambient pressure would make sense for the theoretical calculation. That would mean that at equilibrium, the sum of the partial pressures is 1 atm. You could envision starting with pure sulfuric acid in an airtight but expandable vessel, and heating it up.

For a liquid that just boils, you would have sharp transition between liquid and gas phase at a given temperature. Because of the additional reactions in the gas phase, the situation is more complicated.

> The caption says concentration but the vertical axis says mole(not mole/L or something related to concentration.)

Yes, that is strange. There is not enough information in the paper to figure out what assumptions they are making in their calculation, but they are showing amount of substance in the graph, not concentration.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the graph. Your explanation helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using the term concentration in the chart legend is misleading. The chart represents molar fraction of particular (phase of) compounds as a function of absolute temperature, taking as the initial composition $\pu{1 mol}$ of pure sulfuric acid. It also means the compound molar amounts are numerically also their molar fractions.

Concentrations of gaseous compounds can be approximately  calculated using ideal gas approximation:

$$c_{i,\text{g}}=\frac{n_{i,\text{g}}}{V}=\frac{n_{i,\text{g}}p}{\sum{(n_{i,\text{g}})}RT}=\frac{x_{i,\text{g}}p}{RT}$$

Where

- $c_{i,\text{g}}$ is amount concentration of gaseous compound $i$.
- $n_{i,\text{g}}$ is the molar amount of gaseous compound $i$.
- $\sum{(n_{i,\text{g}})} \le \pu{1 mol}$ is the sum of amounts of
  gaseous compounds.
- $1 - \sum{(n_{i,\text{g}})}$ is the amount of liquid sulfuric acid.
- $V$ is the total volume of gaseous compounds at the assume pressure $p$ and absolute temperature $T$.

The pressure is obviously atmospheric pressure, there is no reason for otherwise.

Molar fractions from the chart cannot be used directly in the formula, as the formula relates only to gaseous compounds, so the total amount of gaseous compounds is less than $\pu{1 mol}$ by the amount of remaining liquid sulfuric acid.

Therefore:

$$x_{i,\text{g}}=\frac  {x_{i,\text{chart}}} {x_{\ce{H2SO4(l)}}}$$

$$c_{i,\text{g}}=\frac{x_{i,\text{chart}}p}{x_{\ce{H2SO4(l)}}RT}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answering.But I still can't understand this graph well. There's H2SO4 in the graph. It seems to represent liquid not gas(because there's gas H2SO4).

Comment: And that is the reason of the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: It seems my question was something different. If we think about ,say water,  and temperature is 100℃ then there would be gap in the equilibrium graph.(water(l) and water(gas) (water in box with 1 atm pressure). I wonder why there's no such a thing in this graph of sulfuric acid. This seemed very odd to me.

Comment: It is because H2SO4 never reaches true boiling point. It's partial pressure tries to raise, but this is progressively overruled by its decomposition.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood. I didn't  distinguish the difference between true boiling point and the point when total vapor pressure is 1 atm.